# Iterm2 saving command history in ssh session

Tags: iterm2

[Toobelt-Command History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28cxj.png)

While using Toobelt-Command History, how to log the history commands in ssh? I can only see local history commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [shell integration](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html) on the the machine you are sshing into. You then will have command history for that machine.

```
curl -L https://iterm2.com/misc/install_shell_integration.sh | bash
```